# how to fix Could not find androidx.databinding:viewbinding:7.0.3. issue

Tags: android-viewbinding

i tried to fix this issue but seems my way is not correct. the error is:
Could not find androidx.databinding:viewbinding:7.0.3.
Required by:
project :app

any solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what solution you did for this issue